# Haskell State monad with tuples as state

Tags: haskell, state, monads

My apologies if my question is stupid (I'm still quite new to monads), but I couldn't find the answer to it so far.

I want to store pairs as the state in the State monad. However, if I try this on a simple example of (Int, Int) I get (ghci):

```
Prelude> import Control.Monad.State
Prelude Control.Monad.State> :t get :: State Int Int
get :: State Int Int :: State Int Int
Prelude Control.Monad.State> :t get :: State (Int, Int) Int

<interactive>:1:1:
    No instance for (MonadState
                       Int (StateT (Int, Int)  Data.Functor.Identity.Identity))
      arising from a use of ‘get’
    In the expression: get :: State (Int, Int) Int
```

My questions are:
1. Why?
2. How do I get this to work?

Comment: If you are new to monad transformers, importing `Control.Monad.Trans.State` instead of `Control.Monad.State` can make things easier to understand (e.g. more clear error messages etc.)

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Now this is interesting. As you might have expected, my original problem was a much more complicated version of the one I presented in my question. Using `Control.Monad.Trans.State` helped me find where the problem actually was (and it was a completely different thing). Thank you for that comment, it helped me solve my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `get` is

```
get :: State s s
```

So if `s = (Int, Int)` then you want

```
get :: State (Int, Int) (Int, Int)
```

That's all. `get` returns the entire tuple.

Comment: That `=` should be `~`, as in type equality, right?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with what GHC uses for type equity constraints; I was just trying to write something that an average person would understand.